# How to get Geolocation data and send it from browser to express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, geolocation, ejs

I want to get the latitude and longitudes of a location.I am using ejs files.
I found this code on w3shools.But i dont know how to include it in ejs file and return the data back to server.In the backend I am uusing express.Can u please help?Thanks in advance.

```css
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I am getting error navigator is not defined when i am writing this code in ejs file

Comment: @doublesharp please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Navigator undefined in ejs file express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62863560/navigator-undefined-in-ejs-file-express)

Answer (score 0):

In your main nodeJS file you need to create a route for receiving the geolocation data:

```
const express = require("express");
const { json } = require("body-parser")
const app = express();
app.use(json())
//you probably have the lines above in your code

app.get("/geolocation/:latitude/:longitude", (req, res) => {
    const latitude = req.params.latitude;
    const longitude = req.params.longitude;
    res.status(200).json({"Message": "Coordinates received"})
    //now that you have these in variables on your server, you can process them or store them in your database as you please
})
```

On the frontend side, in your showPosition function, you should include a fetch request that is going to send the latitude and longitude to your server. To see more about fetch, click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

I hope I understood the question right and this will be useful

Comment: Hey!Thanks for replying!In the ejs file I am getting error as navigator is not defined.What can i do to solve this?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help with that, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

if you want to execute your code from ejs then you need to put it inside `<script>` tag in .ejs file

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

or store all your JS code to separate page and link at bottom in ejs

yourFile.js:

```
(function() {
    var x = document.findElementById('demo');
    ...
)}();
```

Then on your ejs template: //at the bottom of the page

```
<script src="yourFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```