# Navigator undefined in ejs file express

Tags: node.js, express, geolocation, ejs

I want to get the latitude and longitude of the user's location. In the ejs file I am getting error navigator undefined.Can somebody please help?Thanks in advance.

```
<%if ('geolocation' in navigator) { console.log("geolocation supported"); } %>
<%else { console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser."); }%>
```

Updated code:

````
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Daily Journal</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
    </head>
   <body>
  <p>Testing</p>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
    <div class="footer-padding"></div>
      <div class="footer">
        <p>Made with ❤️ by The App Brewery</p>
      </div>
      <script>
        if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
            console.log("geolocation supported");
        } else {
            console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
    ```
Error:
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\API-App\ejs-challenge\public\weather.js:2
  if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
    at C:\Users\HP\Desktop\API-App\ejs-challenge\public\weather.js:2:24
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\API-App\ejs-challenge\public\weather.js:9:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\API-App\ejs-challenge\app.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ejs`-template is rendered on your node-server, where no reference to `navigator` (or `window` for that matter) exists. What you can do, however, is to include above code in a `<script>`-tag and return this in your template:

```
// your-template.ejs
<h1>Hello EJS World </h1>

<script>
    if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
        console.log("geolocation supported");
    } else {
        console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey thank you for replying!I tried what you said ,I am still getting the same error. Navigator is not defined

Comment: Can you add the updated template and the exact error?

Comment: Yep.I did it in the post.

Comment: Seems like I'm not able to reproduce this. If I take your template-code and put it into a file called `test.ejs` and render this using express' `res.render('test');` there's no error and `geolocation supported` is logged in the console.

Comment: okay.What can I do now?Any idea what the error could be?

Comment: app.get("/",function(req,res){
  res.render('header');
});

Comment: Weird - that looks correct. Is your code maybe on github or can you share it on https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: Hey.I tried writing the same code on codesandbox ,it keeps giving me wierd errors.Can you please share your code on codesandox please?

Comment: Sure -> https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-hawking-voegl

Comment: It is working now.Thank u so much!U saved my project!